# Find all $scattered$ numbers less than $2^n$ whose in its binary expansion there are never two 1's immediately next to each other

Tags: combinatorics, exponentiation, binary, binary-operations

Any positive integer can be written in binary (also called base $2$ ). For example, $37$ is $100101$ in binary ( because $37=2^5+2^2+2^0)$, and $45$ is $101101$ in binary. Let's say that a positive integer is '$scattered$' if, in its binary expansion, there are never two ones immediately next to each other. For example, $37$ is $scattered$ but $45$ is not. How many scattered numbers are there less than $4$ ? Less than $8$ ? Less than $2^n$?
I have thought it by the length of the number and made a recursion $a_n= a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}$.May be this can help. Any other help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use Recursion. $f(n)$ denotes the # of satisfying $n$ digit numbers.  $f(n,0), f(n,1)$ denote the respective subsets that end in $0$ or $1$, reading left to right.  So, $f(n,0) + f(n,1) = f(n).$  Then, $f(n+1,0) = f(n)$ and $f(n+1,1) = f(n,0) = f(n-1).$  So $f(n+1) = f(n) + f(n-1).$

Comment: Can you prove this recursion ? Then, it should be possible to establish a formula for $a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was made possible by the significant hint given by @user2661923.

Let **$\boldsymbol{f(n)}$ denote the number of *scattered* binary strings with $\boldsymbol{n}$ terms**, and let $a_n$ denote an arbitrary *scattered* binary string with $n$ terms.
$a_n$ can end with a $0$ or a $1$.

Suppose $a_n$ ends with a $0$. Then, we can remove the last term to produce a binary string which is still *scattered*. Conversely, this implies that for every $a_{n-1}$ (there are $f(n-1)$ such strings), one can form $f(n-1)$ *scattered* binary strings of length $n$ by concatenating a $0$.

Now, if $a_n$ ends with a $1$, then we'll have to modify our earlier reasoning. We know that the last two terms of $a_n$ will be $01$. (Note: we will not consider the case $n = 1$, where $a_n = 1$, since our recursion will start for $n \ge 3$). So, if we remove the $01$, we'll arrive at another *scattered* binary string of length $n-2$. Conversely, for every $a_{n-2}$ (there are $f(n-2)$ of these), one can form $f(n-2)$ strings of length $n$ by concatenating $01$.

Since we have covered all the cases, we can establish a recurrence relation. We need to calculate $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ manually, which is easy. We get:
$$\color{green}{f(1) = 2}$$$$\color{green}{f(2) = 3}$$ and
$$\color{green}{f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) \text{ for all } n \ge 3}$$

Comment: But it is told to find out the number of scattered numbers less than 2^n.

Comment: By the recurrence relation can we get the number of scattered numbers less than $2^n$ by putting values of n ???

Comment: It is not told that to find number of scattered numbers with n terms , it can be also $n-1$ or $n-2$ terms ?

Comment: let us say you want scattered numbers of length $16 = 2^4$, so by the recurrence relation $f(1) = 2, f(2) = 3, f(3) = 2+3 = 5, f(4) = 3+5 = 8$. These 8 strings are $0000,1000,0100,0010,0001,1010,0101,1001$.

Comment: I hope I answered your first question

Comment: Thank you for clarification.

Comment: If I've understood the second question correctly, you're asking whether this method counts numbers which can be well represented using $n-1$ or $n-2$ or even $1$ terms. So, in the example in the previous comment, the numbers $0010_2 = 10_2 = 2_{10}, 0101_2 = 101_2 = 5_{10}$ are a few examples. Thus it can also be $n-1$ or $n-2$ terms, i.e., $f(n)$ is the final answer.

Comment: Very much thanks for clarification

Comment: @Adam100 For the closed form expression that you requested, see [Wikipedia - Fibonacci Sequence Closed Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression).